# Vagrant / PuPHPet errors on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, vagrant, puphpet

The company I work for has decided to embrace "Vagrant" in a LAMP setup.  Being as I am the first to touch the code base between teams, I opt'd to setup the "Vagrantfile".  My team works on Mac Book Pro's OSX and Vagrant has been a dream, however, when we head further up the development work flow, the team on that end uses Windows and they are experiencing a lot of difficulties.  I have headed home where I too use Windows and can recreate the error.

It starts here:

```
: command not foundnt/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 2:
```

Notice the oddness about the term "command not found" being imposed into the string containing the error to the URL.

I have a whole string of issues:

```
: command not foundnt/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 9:
'=> default: grep: invalid option -- '
==> default: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
==> default: Try grep --help' for more information. ==> default: /vagrant/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected tokenelif'
'=> default: /vagrant/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 15: elif [ -f '/etc/redhat-release' ]; then : command not foundnt/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 2: : command not foundnt/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 9: '=> default: grep: invalid option -- ' ==> default: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]... ==> default: Trygrep --help' for more information.
==> default: /vagrant/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token elif' '=> default: /vagrant/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 15:elif [ -f '/etc/redhat-release' ]; then
: command not foundnt/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 2:
: command not foundnt/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 9:
'=> default: grep: invalid option -- '
==> default: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
==> default: Try grep --help' for more information. ==> default: /vagrant/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected tokenelif'
'=> default: /vagrant/puphpet/shell/os-detect.sh: line 15: `elif [ -f '/etc/redhat-release' ]; then
```

I am sure this is a character issue between OSX and Windows but I am unable to detect the problem.

Comment: using `dos2unix` I have been able to clear the issues above.

Comment: My new issue surrounds the box becoming unresponsive. `DEBUG ssh: stdout:

DEBUG ssh: stderr: Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn

 INFO interface: info: Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
 INFO interface: info: ==> default: Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
==> default: Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not related to Vagrant or PuPHPet at all, which is why I was unable to pull an error from Vagrant or the VM.  The issue was with my gateway that was throttling the connection from the VM and thus it was not "erroring" out but just downloading the packages from "yum" very very slowly.